# Azure Data Flow create many databases in SQL Elastic Pool from one database

Tags: azure, azure-elasticpool, azure-data-factory

I'm quite new in 'Azure'. Is it possible to create many databases in SQL Elastic Pool by Azure Data Factory (Data Flow)?

Given:

> ### Table
>
> Row1 | Value1
>   Row2 | Value2

After execution I need to get two databases in specific elastic pool. One DB named: "Value1", second DB named: "Value2".

Comment: How many database do you want to create? Where is the Table?

Comment: @LeonYue I will have around 300 databases. Source table is in DB in Azure SQL. I know how to get data but don't know how to create databases dynamically with Data Flow

Comment: According my experience, Data Flow doesn't have the feature or component can help you create the databases.  We can not do that with Data Flow.

Comment: Any other idea is that you can create a stored procedure which create database in elastic pool with source column data in sink database, using Foreach to copy data from source table and call the stored procedure in sink.

Comment: Possibly it can work, need to try. In the end I will also need to create separate users with read-only permissions for each DB separately, so probably I will go with simple C# application which will do that. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Should I put this as the answer? Hope you can vote up or accept(mark) it.

Comment: About creating read-only user for each database, you could post another question, maybe others can give you more suggestions.

Comment: @LeonYue Sure, please write as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According my experience, Data Flow doesn't have the feature or component can help you create the databases. We can not do that with Data Flow.

With Data Factory, I have an idea is that you can create a stored procedure which create database in elastic pool with source column data in sink database, using Foreach to copy data from source table and call the stored procedure in sink.

Hope this helps.